# Crontab schedule monthly

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

I would like to schedule my tasks every **x** months on day 1 starting for example, March. I am unsure if this is the syntax I'm looking for (for repeating the job every 4 months):

```
0 0 1 3/4 * /path/to/file
```

The man page for *crontab* does not explain in detail how the steps (/) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it correct in your comment to Abhishek's answer.

```
0 0 1 3,7,11 * /path/to/file
```

In this case the "/" won't do what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, it seems that you originally wanted to do this:

```
0 0 1 3-12/4 * /path/to/file
```

Just like with the other fields, if you want a month range, you have to specify both the start and the finish, separated by a dash. For every odd-numbered month, for example, you can use:

```
0 0 1 1-12/2 * /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax

0 0 1 */4 * /path/to/file

Comment: That will not work if I want to repeat every 4 months starting March. */4 => _1,5,9_, what I was wondering is if it is possible for it to expand to => _3,7,11_

Comment: You can do this 0 0 1 Mar,Jun * /path/to/script